# port forwarding access.log

Tags: nginx, logging, port-forwarding

Problem was localized - **MASQUERADE** (it's modifying original source-IP).
Question is closed, because problem not in port forwarding, but in configuration in general of router server. Thanks all.

**Problem:**
The main problem is that I can't understand from where users connect to me.

If someone could tell me what to read and where to dig - it will be great. Caus I even can't formulate keywords for searching in google :)

**Situation:**
There is two servers on Debian.
First one is router with IP ***77.121.*.**** (static Internet IP)  and second one - with IP ***192.168.0.2*** (internal web-server). 
First server doing port forwarding to second on ports 80, 443 + some other. 
When open ***access.log*** on 192.168.0.2 I've got something like that:

```
77.121.*.* - - [10/Dec/2015:13:31:54 +0200] "GET /SOME_PATH HTTP/1.1" 200 3350 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:44.0) Gecko/     20100101 Firefox/44.0"
```

As you see most of IP connected going from router and I can't understand from where users connect to me. 
I don't care internal user IP but if someone connect from outside I need to know that. For now I can't.

I haven't access to the router server not physical nor over ssh (another department) but I could ask to change some parameters on it if needed.

**0 update**
I'm sure that "outside" server use this command:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -d 77.121.*.* -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.2:80
```

plus one more (can't remember what) for internal users.

Will try to analyze packets and recompile nginx with ***ngx_http_realip_module*** on Monday (Michael Hampton's suggestion). ***(done)***

Comment: I've flagged your question as "unclear what you're asking". Please clarify, so people are able to help you.

Comment: If you access your server's public IP address from *inside* your own network, then both the client and the server will have the same public IP address. If you want to see internal clients logged with their internal IP address, you need them to access the server's internal IP address.

Comment: What is your problem? There is no problem statement in the post, no question at all.

Comment: @DeerHunter The main problem is that I can't understand from where users connect to me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outside server is *reverse proxying* to your inside server, not port forwarding.

You can get the "real" IP addresses in the inside server's logs by configuring the [nginx real IP module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html) on the inside server.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Will try this solution on Monday (I'm afraid to make changes on weekend and when I'm not "near" the sever)

Read a little about reverse proxy. And this module [in this article](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170706-How-do-I-restore-original-visitor-IP-with-Nginx-)
Can I assume that iptables command is acting as reverse proxy? I'm sure that "outside" server use this command:
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -d 77.121.\*.\* -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.2:80
plus one more (can't remember what) for internal users

Comment: OK, that's actually port forwarding, but if that were the case you should already be seeing the actual IP addresses.

Comment: I use nginx 1.6.2 from Debian repository. It was compiled with 'ngx_http_realip_module' support. Thanks for your reply because it helps me to localize problem - **masquerade** :)